# Calling an API that used Windows Authentication from ASP.NET Core 3

Tags: c#, api, authentication, asp.net-core, windows-authentication

So I have a Windows Authentication Web App in ASP.NET Core 3. It's default generated and has Windows Authentication enabled (ticked the "Windows Authentication Box" when creating). How do I access an API and get it's resources (Json-Objects in this case) when it uses Windows Authentication?
I already added this to the launchSettings.json:

```
"windowsAuthentication": true,
"anonymousAuthentication": false,
```

And I added this to the web.config file for hosting later but I don't think it matters as I want to get it running locally in Visual Studio:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <security>
        <authentication>
          <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" />
          <windowsAuthentication enabled="true" />
        </authentication>
      </security>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

How do I make my application prompt the user to login with their credentials to verify access to the data from the api (using Windows Authentication)?

Comment: Are those users in the same Windows Domain? (otherwise creating local Windows user for every user of your site would be ... hard... and pretty much no one knows how to sign in to different Windows domain anyway)

Comment: I'm not sure I got you right, is it your api that you want it secured with Windows Authentication, or another API that you want to pass the credentials to?

Comment: Are you asking about accessing the API directly from the browser, or server-side from a different Web project ?  If they're already logged into the domain on their PC it should not require them to log in again for the API access (if they're accessing it directly from their browser)